# How to wrap variable over Log4j2 with SL4J

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2

Currently, my app needs some values that should be appended to the log message.
Since it's using Log4J2 under SL4J, my first thought was to do a wrapper to the Log4J logger where I could add the new value to the output.

Some blogs pointed I should write a Logger, a LoggerFactory and a Binder. But they are pretty outdated (2011) and no hope to have those codes working with current lib.

I saw also something regarding a ThreadContext that look like what I want to build this test.

So my question is what is the most practical (easy) way to extend the logging mechanism and have some variable I can put/or recover from ThreadContext through this wrapper right in the beginning of log message.

```
logger.info("this is a message"); // Custom logger looks the same as usual
```

but internally it work with some ThreadContext to increment the log message.

```
@Override
public void info(final String format) {
    // get some value from ThreadContext
    // add some value that not exist on ThreadContext
    // use it on format string
    // format = container_name + " - " + GUUID + " - " + format;
    logger.logIfEnabled(FQCN, Level.INFO, null, format);
}
```

**CODE**

```
package hello;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        logger.info("this is a message");
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
17:22:13.718 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  hello.SampleController - this is a message
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
17:22:13.718 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  hello.SampleController - CONTAINERXPTO - 0284-8576-9376-8376 - this is a message
```

references

http://poth-chola.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/custom-slf4j-logger-adapter.html
http://binkley.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/correct-slf4j-logger-wrapping.html
http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/custom-slf4j-logger-adapter.html

Comment: It looks pretty much like the Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) / ThreadContext is what you are looking for:

What is the meaning of your additional values?

Comment: It means to add container and app request info id info to the log that goes to the ELK.

Comment: Ok. Pretty common use case.
Probably this:
http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/
might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: tks, will give it a try. One important requirement, is that all the Fish Tagging keeps wrapped so we can evaluate good code with sonar to avoid dummy behavior.

Comment: Not quite sure what "fish tagging" means. (I guess something like transparently adding information to your logs to relate logging-calls belonging together).

Comment: yes, https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html. You Could add a answer, so I give you the point when it comes to the be the right thing

Comment: Ah, thank you! I somehow failed to notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following blog-post

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/

describes a solution for transparently adding additional - request releated - information to logging calls.

**Edit:**

In short, you'll need to add a servlet-filter to your web app which is used to pick up the information you need on a per-request basis.

Inside this filter you can put the informations in a threadlocal map called MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context)/ThreadContext.
An implementation may look like this:

```
public class RequestInformationFilter implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            MDC.put("variableName", "variableValue");

            chain.doFilter(request, response);

        } finally {
            MDC.remove("variableName");
        }

    }

}
```

Afterwards you can use %X{variableName} in your log pattern to print the value of variableName.

Comment: Ahh sorry, lazy me. I allways thought the internet never forgets ;)

Comment: that was not me, I just did the MDC and it work pretty well. WIll up vote also :). Thanks!